# Font-Awesome-Rails Not Loading Icons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have this in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem "therubyracer"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

I've included this in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

I've then put this in my view:

```
          <%= fa_icon "camera-retro" %>
```

In my browser, I can see the HTML rendered as such:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
```

However, no icon displays.

I can also see font-awesome.css is loading here:

[image]

When I do:

```
          <%= fa_icon "camera-retro", text: "hello there camera" %>
```

I get:

[image]

Here's me adding text to the helper:

I'm sure I've missed something but what?

Comment: Did you restart the server after bundle install?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't there, maybe it has the same color as the background... Also add some text to see what happens: `fa_icon "camera-retro", text: "Take a photo"`

Comment: I can see the text but not the icon... - added pic @crispychicken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a hard copy of the font-awesome.css in my app/assets/stylesheets directory that was causing the issue.  I removed that and the gem worked as expected!

Answer (score 2):

That is a [bug](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/139#issuecomment-14686906).

Try to use

```
@import "font-awesome.css";
```

instead of

```
@import "font-awesome";
```